# So I need to increment the number by 1 from func2 and its defined in func1 and get UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I need to increment the number by 1 from func2 and its defined in func1. Heres code:

```
def func1():
    global number
    number = 0
    func2()
    print(number)

def func2():
    number += 1

func1()
```

When i run it i get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\global.py", line 10, in <module>
    func1()
  File "D:\global.py", line 4, in func1
    func2()
  File "D:\global.py", line 8, in func2
    number += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `global number` inside func2() as well:

```py
def func1():
  global number
  number = 0
  func2()
  print(number)

def func2():
  global number
  number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `number` is not a local variable in the scope of `func2`, you should declare it as `global`.

Change `func2` to:

```
def func2():
    global number
    number += 1
```